# Gitflow - master and develop diverged

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, git-flow

Implemented git branching model as shown below

http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

But my branch develop and master gets diverged  after these steps

Step 1 : merge release into master ( no fast forward)

Step 2 : merge release into develop ( no fast forward)

since merge commit from step 1 will not be available for step 2 ,  develop and master gets diverged.

How to ensure develop and master does not gets diverged. ?

Comment: Is there a serious reason why you choose to do a no-fast-forward in this particular case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `git-flow` model naturally makes `develop` and `master` diverge. There is no way to follow that workflow and ensure that one of `develop` and `master` is always an ancestor of the other.

If you have a look at the commits that are in `master` and not in `develop`, you should see only merge commits:

```
git log develop..master
```

It means that, if you use the following `git-log` command, the output should be empty:

```
git log --no-merges develop..master
```

If you are not satisfied by this answer, please edit your question to explain why it maters for you that `develop` and `master` do not diverge from each other.

Comment: Thanks...I will be assured  my develop branch has not missed any commits of my master.

Comment: @rabin: I have edited my answer to address your concern.